# Looking to substitute Enum value for a variable in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have an existing method which essentially hardcodes an Enum value into it.

What I want to do, however, is to pass an Enum value to the method. Then, substitute the passed in value for the hardcoded field. The value that I want to substitute is: ImpactType.Item3ModerateLimited (at the end of the code).

**Way method is right now:**

```
strRemedyTktResponse = IssueRemedyTicket(sb1.ToString());

private string IssueRemedyTicket(string webServiceErrInfo)
        {
            string strResponse = string.Empty;

            IncidentService.HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WSService webService = new IncidentService.HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WSService();

            try
            {
                webService.AuthenticationInfoValue = new IncidentService.AuthenticationInfo();
                webService.AuthenticationInfoValue.userName = "smocustomer";
                webService.AuthenticationInfoValue.password = "ryder123";
                webService.Timeout = 1000 * 60;

                strResponse = webService.HelpDesk_Submit_Service(
                     new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssignedGroup"].ToString() }  //Assigned_Group
                    , "" //Assigned_Group_Shift_Name
                    , "Ryder System, Inc." //Assigned_Support_Company
                    , "FMS" //Assigned_Support_Organization
                    , "" //Assignee
                    , "Software" //Categorization_Tier_1
                    , "Handheld Computer" //Categorization_Tier_2
                    , "Webservice Failure" //Categorization_Tier_3
                    , "" //CI_Name
                    , "" //Closure_Manufacturer
                    , "" //Closure_Product_Category_Tier1
                    , "" //Closure_Product_Category_Tier1
                    , "" //Closure_Product_Category_Tier3
                    , "" //Product_Model_Version
                    , "" //Closure_Product_Name
                    , "" //Department
                    , "SMO" //First_Name
                    , ImpactType.Item3ModerateLimited
```

**Definition of ImpactType field:**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS")]
    public enum ImpactType {

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1-Extensive/Widespread")]
        Item1ExtensiveWidespread,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2-Significant/Large")]
        Item2SignificantLarge,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3-Moderate/Limited")]
        Item3ModerateLimited,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("4-Minor/Localized")]
        Item4MinorLocalized,
    }
```

*I was thinking about doing something like below, but am getting the following error on the "Name" property.

Cannot convert from 'string' to 'ImpactType'
*

```
private string IssueRemedyTicket(string webServiceErrInfo, int impactType)
        {
            string strResponse = string.Empty;

            IncidentService.HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WSService webService = new IncidentService.HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WSService();

            try
            {
                webService.AuthenticationInfoValue = new IncidentService.AuthenticationInfo();
                webService.AuthenticationInfoValue.userName = "smocustomer";
                webService.AuthenticationInfoValue.password = "ryder123";
                webService.Timeout = 1000 * 60;

                var value = "";
                if (impactType == 2)
                    value = ImpactType.Item2SignificantLarge.ToString();
                else
                    value = ImpactType.Item3ModerateLimited.ToString();

                strResponse = webService.HelpDesk_Submit_Service(
                     new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssignedGroup"].ToString() }  //Assigned_Group
                    , "" //Assigned_Group_Shift_Name
                    , "Ryder System, Inc." //Assigned_Support_Company
                    , "FMS" //Assigned_Support_Organization
                    , "" //Assignee
                    , "Software" //Categorization_Tier_1
                    , "Handheld Computer" //Categorization_Tier_2
                    , "Webservice Failure" //Categorization_Tier_3
                    , "" //CI_Name
                    , "" //Closure_Manufacturer
                    , "" //Closure_Product_Category_Tier1
                    , "" //Closure_Product_Category_Tier1
                    , "" //Closure_Product_Category_Tier3
                    , "" //Product_Model_Version
                    , "" //Closure_Product_Name
                    , "" //Department
                    , "SMO" //First_Name
                    ,  ((XmlEnumAttribute)typeof(ImpactType)
                        .GetMember(value.ToString())[0]
                        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlEnumAttribute), false)[0]).Name
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it isn't as simple as treating it like a normal parameter? That is: `private string IssueRemedyTicket(string webServiceErrInfo, ImpactType impactType)` and passing it into the `webService.HelpDesk_Submit_Service` call like: `, impactType`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you trying to get the `XmlEnumAttribute` value? If so, you can use reflection as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737950/get-xmlenumattribute-from-enum

Comment: @keyboard, I'm getting the following error when I write use that code:

Comment: Arugment 18: cannot convert from 'string' to 'ImpactType'

Comment: Also, is 0 the index of the item you want to get. If I want to use the 'SignificantLarge' type, I would use the index of 1?

Comment: this error occurs when using the .Name property at the end of the code I used.

Comment: @sagesky36 Could you edit your question and post that new piece of code please

Comment: @keyboard, I just edited the code. See Edit #1.

Comment: @keyboard, see Edit #2 for latest.....

Comment: @sagesky36 you've added "Edit" blocks with more of the same code but without any indication of what you have done differently or why. Instead, why not just have one block of the code that reflects what you have tried and what you are asking your question about?

Comment: @crashmstr & keyboardP, I just have one code block now for the issue. Please take a look and let me know what the simple conversion error is that I'm missing......

Comment: @keyboardP, I just have one code block now for the issue. Please take a look and let me know what the simple conversion error is that I'm missing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16039343/380384

you want to convert an `int` into an `enum` of `ImpactType`. All you need is this:

```
ImpactType type = (ImpactType)impactType;
```

or

```
, ...
, "SMO" //First_Name
, (ImpactType)impactType
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That was so much easier :)

Comment: btw, the impactType field. Would that be the index of the Enum value? So, if I want the first value from the Impact Enum the impactType would be 0, etc?

Comment: Yes, unless you specify a different values to be used.